# Using Hyperlinks with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, hyperlink

Should the python code below work with a hyperlink in ArcMap 10.1 with python 2.7 installed?

```
import arcpy
def OpenLink ([PARCEL]):
parcel = [PARCEL]
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
subID = parcel[1:7]
folder = "rc" + subID[:1] + "00000"
filename = "s" + subID + "f.tif"
rasterPath = "r:\\rectsubr\\" + folder + "\\" + filename
lyr = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(rasterPath, filename)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "TOP")
return
```

This code works in ArcMap 10.2 and up.

Comment: What happened when you tested it at ArcGIS 10.1?

Comment: No,it won't, because all indentations wrong.

Comment: where are you running this?  From a script tool or from field calculator or somewhere else?